# pouchdb size increasing whilte deleting and restoring docs

Tags: pouchdb

I've noticed that the size of my DB is increasing after deleting / restoring docs with auto-compaction set to `true`. What do I do wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var db = new PouchDB("myDB", {adapter: "idb", auto_compaction: true});
var docs = [{_id: "0", name: "foo1"}, {_id: "1", name: "foo2"}];
db.bulkDocs(docs).then(function() {
    db.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then(function(result) {
        docs = result.rows.map(function(row) {
            return row.doc;
        });   
    };
};

function remove() {
    for (var i in docs) {
        docs[i]._deleted = true;
    } 
    return db.bulkDocs(docs);           
};

function restore() {
    for (var i in docs) {
        delete docs[i]._deleted;
        delete docs[i]._rev;
    } 
    return db.bulkDocs(docs);   
}

// Calling this function increases the size of the DB
function test() {
    return remove(docs).then(restore);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way to delete documents from PouchDB.

Use: `db.remove(doc, [options], [callback])`

[Please check here](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#delete_document)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) Even if you are using auto-compaction, the database size might increase, because the underlying storage engine may have its own quirks. For instance, if you are using the SQLite Plugin, then SQLite may require an explicit `VACUUM` command to decrease the size. Otherwise it will decrease the on-disk size when it feels like it. So it depends on how you are measuring the size.

2) Even if you are using auto-compaction, PouchDB will always store the *revision hash* of the old revisions. In other words, it keeps a record of the entire revision history of the document, usually represented by an array of string hashes. In practice, with auto-compaction, this means that the database will increase by the size of a string like `'19136B05-18F9-CCBF-96C1-6AC11EE9B06E'` for every revision.